# http file upload response structure

Tags: java, http, file-upload

i am trying to create an http file upload receiver in java

and i was looking at the post response of file upload in http

```
POST /upload?upload_progress_id=12344 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Length: 1325
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
<other headers>

------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

100000
------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="hello.o"
Content-Type: application/x-object

<file data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L--
```

if the `boundary` string will be a part of the file that is being uploaded (by coincidence) how can i detect it ? is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as [section 4.1 of RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-4.1) states:

> 4.1 Boundary
>
> As with other multipart types, a boundary is selected that does not occur in any of the data.

So I guess that your browser will probably be smart enough to choose an appropriate boundary.